# Efficient 1D array comparison, scaling and summation

Tags: python, arrays, performance, sorting, numpy

I am facing a performance issue because of a piece of python code that should do the following:

I have 2 arrays A and B with unsorted values and I want to construct a new array C that would contains for each index i the following:

```
C[i]= sum(flag*B[k] for k so that flag = A[k]<=A[i])
```

I have done it in two ways:

1) pretty direct way:

```
M = len(A)
C = np.zeros(M)
for i in xrange(M):
    value = A[i]
    flag = A <= value
    C[i] = np.sum(flag * B)
```

2) trying to use numpy sort function:

```
indices_sorted = np.argsort(A)
C_sort = np.zeros(M)
for i in xrange(M):
    index = np.where(indices_sorted==i)
    for k in xrange(index[0][0]+1):
        C_sort[i] += B[indices_sorted[k]]
```

The result is that the first one is much faster (factor 40-50) for 5000 elements arrays.

I wasn't expecting the second one to be that bad, and the first attempt is not fast enough neither...

Could you guys give me a better way to do that??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your explanation is missing something  - "so that A[k]" what? Could you give a complete reproducible example including your expected output?

Comment: I think you misread, it says:
A[k]<=A[i]

Comment: Well it does now, after this edit: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33923805/2

Comment: sorry I am a newbye as a poster here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `A` and `B` to be 1D arrays of the same shape, you can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by extending `A` to a 2D array and then doing the comparison, thus basically doing comparison of each element with every other element in a vectorized manner. Then, perform elementwise multiplication with `B`, where again `broadcasting` comes into play. Finally sum along the second axis for the final output. The implementation would look like this -

```
C = ((A <= A[:,None])*B).sum(1)
```

You can simulate the same behavior of `elementwise multiplication and summing` with  `matrix-multiplication` using [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for a much more efficient solution, like so -

```
C = (A <= A[:,None]).dot(B)
```

Here's another approach based on indexing with [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) and counting with [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
row,col = np.nonzero(A <= A[:,None])
C = np.bincount(row,np.take(B,col))
```

For huge datasizes, the memory overhead with creating the `2D` mask of `(A <= A[:,None]` might be offsetting the performance. So, as an optimization to the existing loopy code, you can introduce `matrix-multiplication` to replace the elementwise multiplication and summation. Thus, `np.sum(flag * B)` could be replaced by `flag.dot(B)`. Bringing in few other optimization tricks, you would have a modified version like so -

```
M = len(A)
C = np.empty(M)
for i in xrange(M):
    C[i] = (A <= A[i]).dot(B)
```

**Finally!** Here's the winner with [`np.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) -

```
idx = A.argsort()
C = B[idx].cumsum()[idx.argsort()]
```

Here's a quick explanation on how and why it works :

You are performing elementwise comparison and then summing elements from B based on the comparison results. Now, if `A` were a sorted array, then output `C` would essentially be `cumsum` version of `B`. Thus, for a generic unsorted case, you need to sort `B` by argsort of `A`, perform `cumsum` on it and finally re-arrange the elements based on the original unsorted order.

---

**Runtime tests**

Define approaches -

```
def org_app(A,B):
    M = len(A)
    C = np.zeros(M)
    for i in range(M):
        value = A[i]
        flag = A <= value
        C[i] = np.sum(flag * B)
    return C

def sum_based(A,B):
    return ((A <= A[:,None])*B).sum(1)

def dot_based(A,B):
    return (A <= A[:,None]).dot(B)

def bincount_based(A,B):
    row,col = np.nonzero(A <= A[:,None])
    return np.bincount(row,np.take(B,col))

def org_app_modified(A,B):
    M = len(A)
    C = np.empty(M)
    for i in xrange(M):
        C[i] = (A <= A[i]).dot(B)
    return C

def cumsum_trick(A,B):
    idx = A.argsort()
    return B[idx].cumsum()[idx.argsort()]
```

Setting up inputs and timings -

```
In [212]: # Inputs
     ...: N = 5000
     ...: A = np.random.rand(N)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(N)
     ...: 

In [213]: %timeit org_app(A,B)
     ...: %timeit sum_based(A,B)
     ...: %timeit dot_based(A,B)
     ...: %timeit bincount_based(A,B)
     ...: %timeit org_app_modified(A,B)
     ...: %timeit cumsum_trick(A,B)
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 266 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 411 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 322 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.01 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 196 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 835 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar,

I appreciate the elegant way of your solution, but performance-wise I have the following:

Mine 1 : 0.2s
Mine 2 : 8.4s
Yours 1 : 0.34s
Yours 2 : 0.23s

My first method is still the most efficient, do you have an idea why?

Comment: @MichaelB Both `A`  and `B` are 1D NumPy arrays of 5000 elements each, right?

Comment: So the modified version of my first take is a bit better, now it takes 0.14s

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! it has been very interesting reading your different approaches and getting a better one is even cooler.

Comment: I have seen on another post people using cython to fasten even more the computation, do you think we could use this package here?

Comment: @MichaelB Did you check out the just added `cumsum` based approach? That blew off all other approaches!

Comment: Awesome... and now I need to understand how you did the magic :) Brilliant !!! Big thank to you !!!

Comment: @MichaelB Glad to help! Good luck! :)